# Hibernate. Выборка объекта имеющего сразу две связи: ManyToMany и OneToMany

Tags: java, база-данных, spring, hibernate, hql

Пытаюсь выбрать из БД все значения, но дублируются выбираемые значения. Из используемых средств стандартная настройка Spring Boot + Hibernate.

Например, есть сущности: `Клиент`, `Телефон` и `Заказ`, где связи

```
     __Клиент__             __Заказ__
    |          |           |         |
    |          | M ----- M |         |
    |__________|           |_________|
         1
         |
         |
         M
    __Телефон__
   |           |
   |           |
   |___________|
```

HQL запрос выборки:

```
`SELECT DISTINCT T
     FROM Customer T 
     LEFT JOIN FETCH T.orders
     LEFT JOIN FETCH T.phones`
```

При выборке всех сущносей `Клиент` тянутся задублированные строки сущности `Телефон`, (насколько я понял для каждой строки `Заказ`). Если добавить группировку по идентификатору `Телефон`:

`SELECT DISTINCT T
         FROM Customer T 
         LEFT JOIN FETCH T.orders
         LEFT JOIN FETCH T.phones T1
         GROUP BY T1.id`

то количество строк сущности `Телефон` будет правильным, но тогда пропадут все кроме единственной строки сущности `Заказ`.

Помогите разобраться, как решается такая проблема, возможно есть встроенные в Spring/Hibernate решения?

**UPDATE**

Customer:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<Phone> phones = new HashSet<>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "CUSTOMER_ORDER", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID"))
    @OrderBy("id ASC")
    public Set<Order> getOrders() {
        return this.orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(Set<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderBy("id ASC")
    public Set<Phone> getPhones() {
        return phones;
    }

    public void setPhones(Set<Phone> phones) {
        this.phones = phones;
    }

    public void addPhone(Phone phone) {
        phone.setCustomer(this);
        getPhones().add(phone);
    }
}
```

Comment: Все значения чего вы пытаетесь выбрать? Сформулируйте четче

Comment: А почему бы телефоны клиентов не выбирать одним запросом, а заказы - другим? Зачем это всё пытаться затолкать в один запрос?

Comment: @Barmaley все значения всех сущностей, начиная с `Клиент` как указано в HQL запросе, это же `Customer`. Далее в сущности `Customer` с помощью ключевого слова `FETCH` прошу Hibernate выбрать все сущности `Orders` и `Phone` соответственно

Comment: @Regent необходимо иметь доступ ко всем данным, для вывода информации в тот же отчет, например. Предлагаете выбирать вторым запросом, скажем, значения `Телефон` и добавлять их к отчету?

Comment: @Алексей да. С Hibernate я не работал - не знаю как там выбираются значения. Также неизвестно как у вас формируется отчет, но с точки зрения SQL, думаю, проще в реализации и быстрее в исполнении SQL-сервером будет вариант с двумя запросами.

Comment: @Regent спасибо! похоже, что в таком случае, действительно, невозможно выбрать все в одном запросе даже обычным SQL запросом

Comment: @Алексей я так и не врубаюсь, что значит все значения... наверное природная скудость ума не позволяет понять вашу мысль...

Comment: @Barmaley хочу чтобы Hibernate выдал мне список всех `Клиентов`. Выбирая из БД всех `Клиентов` он также выберет все `Заказы` и вставит их в каждый из объектов `Клиент`. Тоже самое со всеми значениями `Телефон` все выбранные значения добавятся в каждый объект `Клиент`. Таким образом у меня будет список объектов всех Клиентов и в каждом из объектов Клиент у меня будет список всеx относящихся к этому клиенту Заказов и его Телефоны)

Comment: @Алексей а что нельзя просто `select distinct T from Customer` - вы получите список всех уникальных клиентов... Как только вы начнете привязывать к клиентам телефоны/заказы вы получите дублирование клиентов - это ж понятно...

Comment: В Entity Клиента перед геттером Заказа поставьте `@JsonIgnore`

Comment: @Barmaley дубли пропали, после того как в сущности для атрибута принимающего множественные значения указал тип данных Set<> а не List<>. Не знаю с чем это связано... Никто не сталкивался?

Comment: @user3841429 там дела еще до Json не доходит, от самого Hibernate приходят задублированные значения

Comment: У вас же есть Entity Customer? можно на него посмотреть?

Comment: @user3841429 да, конечно, добавил

Comment: @Алексей поставьте перед getOrders() `@JsonIgnore`. хотябы для эксперимента. тогда не будет зацикливания

Comment: @user3841429 `@JsonIgnore` не помог, как я и говорил, если поменять тип данных с `Set` на `List`, то замножатся значения. Так если указать `List` для множества значений `Phone`, то каждое значение `Phone` умножится на количество значений `Order`. Т.е. например, 2 записи `Phone` умножатся на все 50 заказов и получится в сущности `Phone` 100 записей. У сущности Set таких проблем нет...